# LDAPS for an Azure AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to setup custom AD on azure for access over the internet (ldap)
I followed the steps in this document
[Azure AD Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap)

I am stuck at step 5 - Configure DNS to access the managed domain from the internet
I was able to generate EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS FOR LDAPS ACCESS but cant ping it. I've setup domain services and virtual network in azure but cant figure out what needs to be done for the dns setting to make the AD access over public internet

Answer (score 1):

I just finished setting this up. You won't be able to ping it. The LDAPS server doesn't respond to ping requests. You need to set an A record for the server that matches the certificate you configured when setting up the server. Ex. ldaps.example.com. Then you can try and connect to it using LDP over SSL to test the configuration.